# Probability and Linear Combination

Tags: probability

If you want to write all possible linear combinations of the following two mixed strategies (probabilities):

$\Big(\frac 23,0,\frac 13\Big)$ and $\Big(\frac 12,\frac 12,0\Big)$

> Would it be correct to say all possible linear combinations would be  equal to $(p,q,s)$ where $p+q+s=1$ and where:
>   $p$ takes values between $\Bigr(\frac 12,\frac23\Bigr)$,
>   $q$ takes values between $\Bigr(0,\frac12\Bigr)$,
>   $s$ takes values between $\Bigr(0,\frac13\Bigr)$.

Comment: What have you tried? What about the strategy $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The combo $(p,q,r)=(\frac7{12},\frac2{12},\frac3{12})$ is not a convex combination of $(\frac23,0,\frac13)$ and $(\frac 12,\frac12,0)$.  Just looking at the first coordinate would imply each of the two mixed strategies has coefficient $\frac 12$, which predicts the wrong values for the second and third coordinates.)  But it does obey your inequalities.